# Idiom meaning (Focus on earning a living!)?

Tags: idioms

I'm asking about an English idiom that you would tell a person who is distracted by side issues that affect his/her ability to do their job, an idiom that (in this case) you would tell that person, meaning, (focus only on earning a living!)

Regards.

Comment: This is kind of broad: the distractions could range all the way from a sick child to a gambling habit.

Comment: Im looking for a colloquial English quote in the form of an order. In Egypt we have a saying (Eat bread!) meaning (focus on earning a living!) .....

Comment: Is this intended to be a positive remark or a negative one? Are children "side issues"?

Comment: "keep your eye on the ball" is a bit broader way of saying 'don't be distracted, concentrate on your main objective'.  It can be used for nearly any activity with an objective, not particularly about 'earning a living'.  I think it is a bit more positive in suggesting opportunity to get ahead, than some adages that might almost suggest a daily routine...or even slightly suggesting a degree of 'drudgery' to life.

Answer (score 4):

**Keep your nose to the grindstone**.
[Phrases.org.uk](http://www.phrases.org.uk/meanings/217200.html) gives the meaning as:

> Apply yourself conscientiously to your work.

Several origins are given, and most evoke the idea of close concentration.

Comment: If this is someone who is not yet doing it and you want to tell them to start, "it's time to put your nose to the grindstone."

Comment: The specific phrase would suggest someone who may be in the process of losing focus and needs a reminder.  Your version is perfectly acceptable and suggests someone who has not yet fully applied himself/herself.

Answer (score -1):

Not an easy question. One possibility is "put bread on the table". Another less idiomatic is "stick to paying the bills".

Answer (score -1):

In colonial America, the phrase "Mind your business," as used on the *[Fugio Cent](http://www.coins.nd.edu/ColCoin/ColCoinIntros/Fugio.intro.html)* (the first coinage authorized by the federal government of the US), meant *get to work*.  Coupled with the word *Fugio* ("I fly") and a picture of a sundial on the other side of the coin, this was an admonition from [Ben Franklin](http://www.scvhistory.com/scvhistory/signal/coins/sg012106-coins.htm) to citizens of the new nation to get busy -- they had a country to build.

From a discussion at [Collector's Universe](https://forums.collectors.com/discussion/849219/context-of-the-fugio-mind-your-business-legend):

> Mind Your Business was only half of the legend. The other part -- Fugio -- would have been understandable to most folks in the 18th century, even though it was latin. Fugio means "I fly," referring to the sundial, representing time.
>
> So the full legend is [Time] flies, [so] mind your business.
>
> Or, The clock is ticking, go do what you need to do.